# reading full address using inerop.excel.hyperlinks

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2003

I've added some hyperlinks (images) into an excel file (.xls 2003).
I'm using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Reference to read this hyperlink's address.
But it doesn't show up as the full path location of the image, but only the name (eg image1.jpg).

Here is how I'm doing it.
Below three statements are in a loop.

```
object index = (object)i;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink link = links.get_Item(index);
Debug.WriteLine(link.Address);
```

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a temporary solution which needs further testing with different locations.

I already have an absolute path to the excel file.
And the hyperlink's address is relative to above excel file.

so here is what I did.

```
object index = (object)i;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink link = links.get_Item(index);
string absolutePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(xlpath+link.Address);
Debug.WriteLine(absolutePath);
Bitmap image = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(absolutePath,true);
```

This seems to be working for now but not appropriate solution.
I'm still looking for a better solution.